# Magento 1.9 order comment ADD do backend info

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, backend

I am trying to add a box for customers to place a comment on their order.
I've added it to my

> /checkout/cart/cart.phtml

You can see I added it here

```
  <div class="cart-collaterals">
      <div class="row">
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Comments') ?></th>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">

        <?php echo "Any special requirements regarding this order?"; ?>
        <!-- COmments box -->
        <td class="a-center">
  <textarea name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][comments]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $_item->getItemcomment() ?></textarea>
  </td>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
                <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="cart-totals">
                <span id='ajax_loadertotals' style='display:none'><!--<img src='<?php //echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif')?>'/>--><div class="loaderTotals">Loading...</div></span>
                    <div class="totals">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
                        <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
                            <ul class="checkout-types">
                                <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
                                    <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                                        <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="shipping-info-link">
                  <a href="/checkout-shipping-details/" class="link-quickview" id="delivery-shipping-info">Delivery & Shipping Information</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('giftcard/checkout_cart_giftcard')->setTemplate('mt/giftcard/checkout/cart/giftcard.phtml')->toHtml();
?>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>


    </div>
```

Now my problem comprises here:
How can I make it so I (the sales person) can see it on the backend when the order comes through?

I don't mind changing this to the checkout page if it makes it easier. If you could give me some help with it, I'd really appreciate. I've looked around but didn't find anything useful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)Add custom field/attribute in sales_flat_order table using install script, the sample is given below

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
          ->addColumn(
              $installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'cutom_comment', 'VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL'
          );

$installer->endSetup();
```

2) Add the field into the checkout page

3) You can use the event  "**checkout_type_onepage_save_order**"

4) you can get the value using `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('custom_comment')`

5) get the order details using `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`

6) save the order

```
$order->setCustomComment($comment);
```

7) add a custom layout for admin 
for that [ref](http://www.webspeaks.in/2015/12/magento-add-custom-block-in-admin-sales-order-page.html)

8 ) get order details with  `$order = $this->getOrder()`

9)  get value by `$customComment = "$order->getCustomComment();"`